# How to add borders to image in opencv, border colors must be same as image color

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

How to add borders to image in #opencv, border colors must be same as image color.

Comment: You mean the new border color should be same as the existing border color of the image?

Comment: Yes. Image must be not known inserted border

Comment: Sorry my english is poor

Comment: @JaparJarkinbek If you can't describe it in English, describe it by showing your code or an image of what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OpenCV function [`cv::copyMakeBorder`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36) with `BORDER_REPLICATE`  flag. This will create a new image with extended borders and the value of border will be equal to the border pixel value of original image. It can be achieved as shown in following sample.

```
int borderSize = 2;

cv::copyMakeBorder(input, output, borderSize, borderSize,
               borderSize, borderSize, BORDER_REPLICATE);
```